# Monkey patching third-party library

Tags: python, debugging, monkeypatching

I am using minio client and getting following error:

`minio.error.InvalidEndpointError: InvalidEndpointError: message: Hostname does not meet URL standards.`

This is caused by an incorrect regex in `minio.helpers:281` function `is_valid_endpoint(endpoint)`

An upstream issue is open and I would like to learn how to monkey patch this with `f = lambda: True` when importing the Minio object.

```
from minio import Minio

# credentials['S3_ENDPOINT_URL'] = 'something.westeurope.azurecontainer.io'

minio_client = Minio(credentials['S3_ENDPOINT_URL'],
                     access_key=credentials['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
                     secret_key=credentials['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
                     secure=USE_SSL)
```

Can someone please enlighten me how to monkey patch this? I've only used it for function definitions and not for classes before.

Answer (score 0):

So for monkey patch you can simply replace the function

First define a function that always returns true:

```py
def is_valid_replacer(endpoint):
    return True
```

Then Just replace the function

```py
import minio
minio.helpers.is_valid_endpoint = is_valid_replacer
#### Your code here ####
```

If I understood you this should work.

Comment: Yes, I thought to replace this with my lambda function. However when Minio gets instantiated, the patch is not used.